# Log in to desktop application by Windows Live ID

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-live-id

I want to create a login form for my desktop application that user can use Windows Live ID for that.
I create an application in [manage.dev.live.com](https://manage.dev.live.com) and use [Desktop Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh278363) section.

I use a `WebBrowser` control and navigate to a given address. but I don't know how to receive the token for user.
If I have made a mistake please tell me how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of June 2011, Windows Live ID supports OAUTH 2.0 and should enable you to do that ([read more about it](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/06/14/windows-live-developer-platform-adds-oauth-2-0-and-more-continuing-to-let-users-connect-the-devices-apps-and-sites-they-choose.aspx)).  WPF code example can be found at https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/CSharpDesktop.

Comment: your code link is dead, the new one seems to be https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/tree/master/src/Desktop